# LaTeX equations in Ubuntu's MediaWiki

Tags: ubuntu, latex, installation, mediawiki

My Texvc seems to works, since `texvc /home/wiki/tmp /home/wiki/math "y=x+2"` gives

```
Cdaa63ef966cc412541190bc8794731de<i>y</i> = <i>x</i> + 2<mi>y</mi><mo>=</mo><mi>x</mi><mo>+</mo><mn>2</mn>
```

My **LocalSettings.php** at /var/www/wiki [(source)](http://organicdesign.co.nz/Math_rendering#Example)

```
$IP = "81.111.1.1";
$wgMathPath         = "{$wgUploadPath}/math";
$wgMathDirectory = "{$IP}/images/math";
$wgUploadDirectory  = "{$IP}/images";
$wgUploadPath       = "{$wgScriptPath}/images";
$wgTexvc            = "{$IP}/math/texvc";  # Path to compiled 
texvc
$wgMathDirectory    = "{$wgUploadDirectory}/math";
$wgTmpDirectory     = "{$wgUploadDirectory}/tmp";
```

I go to my wiki in Firefox and I see the output

```
Warning: require_once(81.111.1.1/includes/OutputHandler.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/wiki/includes/WebStart.php on line 123

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '81.111.1.1/includes/OutputHandler.php' (include_path='/var/www/wiki:/var/www/wiki/includes:/var/www/wiki/languages:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/wiki/includes/WebStart.php on line 123
```

I am using my correct IP in the variable $IP at [/var/www/wiki/LocalSettings.php](http://dpaste.com/113534/).
I copied /wiki/includes/DefaultSettigs.php to /wiki/, but Math equations are not still working.

I run unsuccessfully RCS' suggestion about including the PATH to the variable $IP.
I get the similar warning and error as above.

**What would you change in my settings to make Math formulee work?**

Comment: have you tried replacing the variable $IP with the actual IP of your machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the math temp directory exists and the permissions on that directory. I think mode 777 is necessary (i.e., `chmod a+w /path/to/dir`).

There is some further help in the [MediaWiki Manual](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Troubleshooting_math_display_errors#.22Failed_to_parse_.28Can.27t_write_to_or_create_math_output_directory.29.22).

edit: the variable `$IP` is the (local) include path and not an IP-address:

**[Include path](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:LocalSettings.php#Include_path)**:
The $IP (include path) variable holds the local file path to the base installation of your wiki. Make sure you refer to the fully qualified file path. Do not include a slash at the end of the path.
The DefaultSettings.php file gets loaded from the directory designated by the IP variable.

Comment: you can also do
chmod 777 /path/to/directory

Comment: My LocalSettings.php is this http://dpaste.com/113534/. I have not managed to get the Math formulee to work with the path included in the variable $IP.

Comment: Have you tried $IP="/var/lib/mediawiki/" or $IP="/usr/share/mediawiki"?

Comment: The last two values of the variable $IP are not working: I can now see my site again, but LaTeX equations are not visible.

Comment: I gave the bounty to this question because it has the right answer in its body `$IP is the local include path and not an IP-address`. I did not notice it first time reading. -- BTW, I think that the name of the variable $IP is rather confusing, since you do not put any IP-address to that variable.

Answer (score 0):

My mediawiki locates at /var/www/wiki.
However, my $IP refers only to an IP address.
It should also refer to the location of the installation directory.

I changed the $IP variable from `/usr/share/mediawiki` to `/var/www/wiki`
wihout my IP at all. I seem to be able to access my wiki outside of my home though I do not have my IP in the variable.

This change made the Math formulee to work.